# Input String but got a number?

Tags: java, recursion

I tried to use recursion to reverse a string but I got an output of numbers

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
            if(str == null) {
            return null;
            } 
            if(str.length() > 1) {
                int ch = str.charAt(0);
                String withoutFirst = str.substring(1);
                String reverseNoFirst = reverse(withoutFirst);
                String result = reverseNoFirst + ch;
                return result;
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `ch` as a `char`, not `int`:

```
char ch = str.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "int ch = str.charAt(0)" with "String chr=String.valueOf(str.charAt(0));"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).